# Date Formatters in NSDateFormatter

Tags: nsdateformatter

The documentation is not clear about the date formatters

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:MM"];

What are the availabe dateFormats ????

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any* Unicode-compliant date string. Specifications can be found here.

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

*subject to certain locale dependencies. But you're unlikely to run into them for straightforward use cases.